# How can I print out A-Z in Netwide assembler

Tags: linux, loops, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .text 
    global _start
_start:

    mov eax, [inputOrder]
    mov     ecx, inputOrder
    mov     edx, inputLen
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    
    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     0x80

section .data

    inputOrder db 065,066,067,068,069,070,071,072,073,074,075,076,077,078,079,080,081,082,083,084,085,086,087,088,089,090 

    inputLen equ $ - inputOrder
```

I need help. I need to use loop in order to print out A-Z. What is the needed code in order to solve this issue? What will I add in this code in order to make a Loop rather than *inputOrder*?

Comment: With `%rep` / `%endrep`, and `%assign`, you can get NASM to generate that range in `.data` for you, without a run-time loop.  But looping and storing to stack space or something would work well, setting up for one big `write`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov eax, [inputOrder]
> ```

This instruction loads the EAX register with 0x44434241, but then you simply don't use it. To be removed.

A loop as per request, would output a single character, increment the ASCII code for the character and continue until the Z character got processed. There's no need to use an actual `loop` instruction!

```
Again:
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ecx, TheChar
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    movzx   eax, byte [TheChar] ; Retrieving the variable
    inc     eax
    mov     [TheChar], al       ; Updating the variable
    cmp     al, 'Z'
    jbe     Again

    xor     ebx, ebx
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .data

TheChar db 'A'
```

A much faster version will output the characters all together. We will use a loop to construct the alphabetical sequence in a multipurpose buffer located in the .bss section:

```
    mov     eax, 'A'
Again:
    mov     [Buffer - 'A' + eax], al
    inc     eax
    cmp     al, 'Z'
    jbe     Again

    mov     edx, 26             ; All at once
    mov     ecx, Buffer
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    xor     ebx, ebx
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .bss

Buffer resb 4096
```

Another version uses the stack for a buffer and has a loop with fewer iterations:

```
    mov     eax, 'YZ[\'
Again:
    push    eax
    sub     eax, 0x04040404     ; 'YZ[\' -> 'UVWX' -> 'QRST' ... -> 'ABCD'
    cmp     al, 'A'
    ja      Again
    push    eax

    mov     edx, 26             ; All at once
    mov     ecx, esp
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    add     esp, 28             ; Clean stack

    xor     ebx, ebx
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
```

Comment: You don't actually need to load, you could just increment a register and store + `write`.  But yes, you do need to store :P  (Or much better, increment a pointer in a loop and make one `write` system call at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

First you write down what the code would be without `loop`, and then you generalize it so `loop` can be used.
Today, nobody uses `loop` because it’s utterly slow, but if you insist on using `loop`:

```
global _start
bits 64
default rel

section .text

    shr edx, 2                  ;  edx ≔ edx div 4
    test ecx, ecx               ;   ZF ≔ ecx = 0
print:
    mov [rsi], rbp              ; rsi↑ ≔ rbp
    mov eax, edi                ;  eax ≔ edi
    mov esp, ecx                ;  esp ≔ ecx
    syscall                     ; fast system call
                                ; rax, rcx, and r11 are not preserved
    mov ecx, esp                ;  ecx ≔ esp
    lea rbp, [rbp + rbx]        ;  rbp ≔ rbp + rbx
    loopne print                ;  ecx ≔ ecx − 1
                                ; if ecx ≠ 0 ∧ ¬ZF then goto print  
    jecxz $$                    ; if ecx = 0 then goto $$ 
    shr edi, 1                  ;  edi ≔ edi div 2
exit:
    mov eax, 60                 ;  eax ≔ 60
    syscall

_start:
    mov rbp, 'ABCDEFGH'         ;  rbp ≔ 16#4847464544434241
    mov rbx, 0x0808080808080808 ;  rbx ≔ 16#0808080808080808
    mov ecx, 3                  ;  ecx ≔ 3
    setne dil                   ;  dil ≔ ¬ZF
    mov dl, bl                  ;   dl ≔ bl
    mov rsi, rsp                ;  rsi ≔ rsp
    jmp print                   ; goto print
```

Comment: I think we can assume the OP meant they needed to use *a loop*, not "*the `loop` instruction*", and it was a typo or grammatical error that led to "I need to use loop".

Comment: Did you intentionally pick the most confusing and weird way you could to write this?  Using `esp` instead of any other 32-bit register (like `ebx`, and use `r8` for your 64-bit constant that needs a REX on every use anyway) save the loop counter is super weird.  And `jecxz $$` jumps to the top of the `.text` section, but you could just just put a label there.  Similarly, putting `_start` part way down seems to serve no purpose, just costing you a `jmp` instead of falling in to the `shr`.  (Where you could put a label for `jecxz`.  Which BTW costs you an address-size prefix vs. `jrcxz`.)

Comment: `setne dil` depends on the initial state of ZF since you haven't set it yet; it could give you a different result in a dynamically linked executable, and comments don't even say that you're using it to get RDI=1 which you also use as the call number.  This seems like a poor example for anyone of good style or techniques, even leaving aside that you decided that the question was asking for the use of the `loop` instruction.   Also, `bits 64` means it will assemble if the OP builds it with the same commands as their 32-bit code, but then crash at run-time.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The question was very confusing. One `write(2)` of 26 Bytes is _the_ “correct” way. Why would somebody do a loop or `loop` for that? Stackoverflow isn’t a homework solution service, so the presented code is indeed and deliberately difficult to explain. The System Ⅴ ABI says upon process initialization (most of) the (queryable) flags are cleared, i. e. ZF is unset. Preserving `ecx` inside the loop is necessary, because `loop` makes use of it, but `syscall` will overwrite. I don’t think `syscall` or 64‑bit registers are encodeable in 32‑bit code, so assembly should fail.

Comment: Huh, interesting, you're right. I didn't realize RFLAGS had guaranteed values, unlike the integer registers.  The AMD64 SysV ABI says all the integer registers except RSP and RDX can hold garbage.  In practice Linux zeros them in a fresh process, but in a dynamically linked executable, `ld.so` does leave garbage in them before jumping to your `_start`. 
 You're depending on the upper bytes of RDI being zero, both for the `int fd` in EDI and the 64-bit call number in RAX.

Comment: Yes, I know how `loop` and `syscall` work, so of course you have to save/restore RCX across `syscall` if you use `loop`.  But you can use *any* register for that, no need to use `esp`.  If you use `ebx` for save/restore of `ecx`, you can use `r8` for your `0x0808080808080808` constant.  Every instruction that uses it already needs a REX prefix for 64-bit operand-size, so no downside in code-size.  Speaking of which, `[r8 + rbp]` would save a byte vs. `[rbp + r8]` because an RBP base is only encodeable with a `disp8=0`.  Or just use `add rbp, r8`.

Comment: Re: assembling as 32-bit: You put `bits 64` at the top of your file, so `nasm -felf32` will happily assemble 64-bit machine code into a 32-bit ELF object file.  Try it yourself, and look at how it disassembles.  (Also, `syscall` is a valid instruction in 32-bit mode, supported by AMD CPUs only.)

Comment: If you want a clever way to init RDI=1, use `lea edi, [rcx-2]`.  That's also 3 bytes, but doesn't depend on the old value of anything except RCX which you just wrote with a `mov`.  Also, you don't need `syscall` in the loop, you could just `push rbp` 4 times to construct the string on the stack, starting with `'STUVWXYZ'`, maybe with `'YZ[\]...'` so you don't need an offset from RSP to get the address of the `'A'`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I _think_ Linux actually sanitizes system call parameters. Loading `rax` with the “system call number” `60+0x100000000` will successfully trigger `sys_exit`. Similarly, a too large `int fd` won’t cause troubles. I get _errors_ with `nasm ‑felf32` on the line containing `bits 64` and the lines containing m64 operands, as well as `setne dil`. It surprises me though that nothing else caused problems. Thank you for highlighting that I shouldn’t rely on the registers’ contents at startup. `lea edi, [rcx‑2]` is indeed neat and I like the idea of building the string in the scratch zone.

Comment: Interesting; turns out that even before rewriting the syscall dispatch part of the kernel code in C, there was a 32-bit `__SYSCALL_MASK` that if defined would truncate it to 32-bit or lower. 
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L188 .  But the point stands about garbage lower in the register; you definitely need the 2nd byte of EDI to be non-garbage, so it was still a real problem.  `setne dil` only affects the low byte, so you might get `0xabcdef01` which isn't a valid syscall number or 32-bit `fd`.

Comment: What NASM version are you using where `bits 64` doesn't work properly, to allow you to put machine code of a different bitness into any file?  Oh, perhaps it's having a problem trying to make relocation entries for them?  No, your code doesn't use any label addresses, just RSP.  My NASM 2.15.05 doesn't complain.

Comment: @PeterCordes: This is NASM 2.11.08 I am/was having problems with.